# WebSphere Application Server - exportWasprofile for multiple nodes?

Tags: configuration, export, websphere

is there a way for exporting WAS profile which has multiple nodes? exportWasprofile only works for base servers with single node. WAS v6.1 is the version of the product.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but the [manageprofiles.sh](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=pix&product=was-nd-dist&topic=rxml_manageprofiles) command line utility and its -backupProfile and -restoreProfile options might do the trick.  You can find it the *app_server_root*/bin directory